# Connection error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] cakephp bake model and template

Tags: database, templates, cakephp, controller, connection

( macOS Catalina / PHP 7.4.2 / Homebrew and intl installed / MAMP )

1 -  `./cake bake controller users` : It worked for me and display data from database with view function from UsersController created with bake.

But when I do:

2 :  `./cake bake template users` or `./cake bake model users`

I get this error :
Connection to Mysql could not be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

3 : when i try :  `./cake bake template all` or `./cake bake model all`

```
Exception: Connection to Mysql could not be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

in `[/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cake4/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver.php, line 107]`

```
Error: [Cake\Database\Exception\MissingConnectionException] Connection to Mysql could not be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cake4/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver.php on line 107
Exception Attributes: array (
  'driver' => 'Mysql',
  'reason' => 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory',
)
Stack Trace:
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cake4/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver/Mysql.php:114
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cake4/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Schema/BaseSchema.php:47
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cake4/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Dialect/MysqlDialectTrait.php:65
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cake4/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Schema/Collection.php:53
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cake4/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Connection.php:400
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cake4/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Utility/TableScanner.php:65
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cake4/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Utility/TableScanner.php:82
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cake4/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Command/TemplateAllCommand.php:60
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cake4/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/BaseCommand.php:175
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cake4/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/CommandRunner.php:336
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cake4/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/CommandRunner.php:171
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cake4/bin/cake.php:12
```

PS : I already added  `export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.11/bin:$PATH` to ~/.bash_profile

Same error on CakePHP3. Any help?

Comment: Can you access your mysql server via the command line tool from that server? Is it running?